# доступ к диву содержимое которого меняется

Tags: javascript, slider

код-

```
var main1 = document.querySelector("#main1"); 
var a1=document.getElementsByClassName("a")
var img1=["images/11.jpg","images/12.jpg","images/13.jpg","images/14.jpg","images/15.jpg","images/21.jpg","images/22.jpg","images/23.jpg","images/24.jpg","images/25.jpg","images/26.jpg"]
function slide_img(){
    for(var i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
        a1[i].innerHTML="<img src="+img1[i]+" width='img.naturalWidth' height='150px'>"
    }
}

function right(){
    var l=img1.shift()
    img1.push(l)
    slide_img()
}
```

эта функция работает правильно вот только  в console.log-е при вызове дива через идентификатор main1 ,выводит только это

```
<div class="a" id="main1"></div>
```

а если в html вставлено изображение то в консоле почему то оно не меняется , мне надо получить доступ к содержимому,чтоб использовать indexOf

Comment: Карусель делается вообще не так...

Comment: дело не в этом (да и пока что так могу), а в том что  не могу извлечь данные, а должно было работать по моему

Comment: Сделай сниппет или фиддл.

Comment: я месяц как учу яваскрипт , эти термины мне не знакомы (погуглил , посмотрел но лучше  это оставить на потом)

по другому как можно сделать, и в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: @Тигран, сниппет это пример, который можно запустить и увидеть проблему, в режиме редактирования в редакторе вопроса есть кнопка `<>` "вставить фрагмент кода" `Ctrl+M` в открывшемся окне будет три секции для html, js,css в которые можно вставить свой код.разметку стили. Это позволяет добавить рабочий пример непосредственно в вопрос. фиддл - то же самое, но на стороннем сайте [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)